# How to really use multitouch gestures now

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, gestures

So i have a touchscreen now, Ubuntu 10.10, made the gesturetest which works with up to two fingers - but now i have one simple question: how do i enable multitouch so that GNOME understands the gestures - at least two finger scrolling should be possible now - right?

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/142934/29470

Answer (score 2):

Goto `System > Preferences > Mouse`. Click on the Touchpad tab and select two finger scrolling. Click Close and it should now work.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but there is no touchpad tab.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no support currently for two-finger scroll on touch screens.  The current support for two-finger scroll is implemented in the `synaptics` X driver, which is tailored for touch *pad* use, and probably won't behave properly with a touch screen.

So, although you've got two-finger multitouch happening there's not currently any support for turning a two-finger drag gesture into a scroll event.  This needs toolkit (GTK+, Qt, etc) support.  I'd expect the Canonical DX touch team, who are working on the multitouch stack, will implement this support in the next couple of releases.

Since the multitouch protocol stuff is *almost* available in an upstream X server there should soon be more people able to work on this, too; not just people working on Ubuntu.

At the moment (Ubuntu 11.10), this is a missing feature.

Comment: What about Ginn? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn Can it be used to add two-finger support?

Comment: It's 2016, anyone got an update on this?