# How do I configure my touchscreen to scroll?

Tags: xorg, touchscreen, xinput

I like to use my touchscreen to scroll.

```
Device Enabled (121):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (123): 0.365000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.635000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.640000
Device Accel Profile (242): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (243):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (244):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (245):    10.000000
Evdev Axis Inversion (246): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (247):   <no items>
Evdev Axes Swap (248):  0
Axis Labels (249):  "Abs X" (259), "Abs Y" (260)
Button Labels (250):    "Button Unknown" (241), "Button Unknown" (241), "Button Unknown" (241), "Button Wheel Up" (127), "Button Wheel Down" (128)
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (251):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (252):  50
Evdev Wheel Emulation (253):    1
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (254):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (255):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (256):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (257): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (258):  0
```

The [manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/evdev.4.html) from www.x.org says it's the 4th button by default ... but I neither know how to gesture to scroll, nor the buttons 0,1 seem to work.

Comment: Maybe touchpad-ish two fingers?

Comment: i never used touchpad before, must they be close together?

Comment: No, separate. Demonstration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2ZpbIqKl78 But that's for touchpad, I'm not sure if that's true for touchscreens.

Comment: According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604149 scroll works on some hardware. What is yours?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

There is a duplicate question: [How to really use multitouch gestures now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21396/how-to-really-use-multitouch-gestures-now)
And the short answer is

> At the moment (Ubuntu 11.10), this is a missing feature.

But do take a look for additional information.